Inconsistent Connections to Azure SQL Managed Instance with Fabric Notebook
I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL Managed Instance with Microsoft Fabric Notebook using PySpark code. When I attempt to connect, I encounter the following error:
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host db-sql-mi.public.e789gjshb.database.windows.net, port 3342 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

However, if I try connecting 15 times, it occasionally succeeds and returns the output data frame for the specified table. On the other hand, my teammate, who is located in the US (where the SQL instance is also located), can connect and get the output within 2 seconds every time. He is the architect of this project.
I am not very familiar with networking, so I am wondering if location-specific access or network speed is affecting my connection (I am based in India). My architect has whitelisted my public IP address (which I found via a Google search) and I worked the entire day on that specific Wi-Fi connection, but I still experienced issues. It did connect once, but then failed to connect again for the next two hours, though it worked one out of 15 times after that.
If there were an access issue, would it be possible to connect even those 2 times out of 15?
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL Server Example").getOrCreate()
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
server_type = 'sqlserver'
jdbc = 'db-sql-mi.public.e789gjshb.database.windows.net:3342'
dbname = 'db-01'
driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
table_name = 'tbl_name'
schema = 'schema_name'

jdbc_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:{server_type}://{jdbc};databaseName={dbname}") \
    .option("dbtable", f"DBO.{table_name}") \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password",password) \
    .option("driver", f"{driver}") \
    .option("hostNameInCertificate","*e789gjshb.database.windows.net") \
    .option("encrypt",True) \
    .option("trustServerCertificate",False) \
    .option("loginTimeout",180) \
    .load()

display(jdbc_df.limit(10))

I've tried whitelisting the IP ADDRESS with help of my Architect and Connected with Specific given VPN and that's also not working and mimics the same problems

 The TCP/IP connection to the host db-sql-mi.public.e789gjshb.database.windows.net, port 3342 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Network is blocking while connecting to managed instance from fabric notebook to the specified port 3342, that may be the reason to get above error. Make sure you configured public endpoint correctly. Create inbound rule for port 3342 by following this MS document to configure public endpoint.
Even if your IP is whitelisted, there may be other network security settings affecting the connection. So, it's better to use managed private endpoint to reduce network blockage. Configure managed private endpoint to connect azure sql managed instance from fabric notebook by following this MS document. Use below code to connect  managed instance from fabric notebook:
jdbcHostname = "<servername>.database.windows.net"     
jdbcPort = 1433    
jdbcDatabase = "<dbname>"     
jdbcUsername = "<username>"             
jdbcPassword = "<password>"            
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
table = "<tableName>"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbcDriver).option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", table).option("user", jdbcUsername).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()
df.show()

It will give the output as shown below:



EmployeeID
FirstName




1
John


2
Jane


3
Mike


4
Emily



For more information you can refer to similar MS Q&A question.
